# converting json.loads dictionary output to a JSON object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am reading from a URL like below

```
def findPlace():
    url = "https:myurl.com"
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as ur:
        response = ur.read()
    jObj=json.loads(response)
    return jObj
```

The jObj is a dictionary. How can I convert it to a JSON object? I tried to use `json.dump` like below:

```
def findPlace():
        url = "https:myurl.com"
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as ur:
            response = ur.read()
        jObj=json.loads(json.dumps(response))
        return jObj
```

But it throws error `TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable`

Any suggestion?

Comment: `json.loads` should work, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Your last code snippet also has a basic mistake. `response` is bytes from the web, should be passed to `loads` not `dumps` so you must reverse the order: `jObj = json.dumps(json.loads(response))`. That will fix your error however it doesn't make sense because `dumps` and `loads` are the opposite one of the other so you will end up with the same thing you had in first place.

Comment: `json.loads` return `dict` objects.  There's nothing wrong with this.  What hinders you from doing what you need for `jObj` as you might expect from a "`json` object"?